# Dynamically changing the jQuery sortable placeholder value

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I use an if statement in the jQuery sortable plugin to dynamically determine the placeholder class?
If the item is being dragged around in `#listA` then I want the placeholder class to be `.ImInListA`
If the item is being dragged around in `#listB` then I want the placeholder class to be `.ImInListB`

jQuery

```
$( "#listA, #listB" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".connected_sortable",
    placeholder:
    //if the current item is being dragged in #listA
    //use css class selector .ImInListA
    //else
    //use css class selector .ImInListB
}).disableSelection();
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="listA" class="connected_sortable">
  <li value="1">list_a_1</li>
</ul>

<ul id="listB" class="connected_sortable">
  <li value="2">list_b_2</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this:

```
$("#listA li").live('mouseover', function(){
 $( "#listA" ).sortable( "option", "placeholder", 'ImInListA' );
});

$("#listB li").live('mouseover', function(){
 $( "#listB" ).sortable( "option", "placeholder", 'ImInListB' );
});
```

Hope this help someone :)